# How to use add for grid in back boxplot in R

Tags: r

```
df <-data.frame(y=c(69,61,61,78,69,66,68,59,59,75,67,67,69,61,63,77,67,67,68,61,61,76,66,64), x=gl(4,6))

bx.p <- boxplot(y~x, df,main="Accuracy",ylab="Accuracy(%)",xlab="Models",xlim=c(0.5,4.5),ylim=c(55,90),boxfill=0,medcol=2,boxwex=0.4,names=c("a","b","c","d") )

bx.p$stats[3, ] <- unclass(with(df, by(y, x, FUN = mean)))

bxp(bx.p, add=T, boxfill="transparent", medcol="blue", boxwex=0.4,axes=F, outpch = NA, outlty="blank", boxlty="blank", whisklty="blank", staplelty="blank")
legend(x=3.8,y=90.5, lty=c(1, 1), lwd=rep(3, 2), col=c("red", "blue"), box.lwd=0.2,legend = c("median", "mean"), cex=0.8,horiz = FALSE, bg="transparent")

grid(nx=13, ny=13)

add=TRUE is not applied
```

It doesn't change although i add (add=TRUE)

```
bx.p <- boxplot(y~x, df,main="Accuracy",ylab="Accuracy(%)",xlab="Models",xlim=c(0.5,4.5),ylim=c(55,90),boxfill=0,medcol=2,boxwex=0.4,names=c("a","b","c","d"),add=TRUE )
```

[image]

Comment: What is your question? What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

You can add them manually if you like by using the `segments()` function in base R plots:

```
df <-data.frame(y=c(69,61,61,78,69,66,68,59,59,75,67,67,69,61,63,77,67,67,68,61,61,76,66,64), x=gl(4,6))

plot(x = c(50,90), y = c(0,10), xlab = NA, ylab = NA, axes = FALSE, type = "n")
bx.p <- boxplot(y ~ x, df, main="Accuracy",
                ylab = "Accuracy(%)", xlab = "Models",
                xlim = c(0.5,4.5), ylim = c(55,90),
                boxfill = "white", medcol = 2, boxwex = 0.4,
                names = c("a","b","c","d") )

bx.p$stats[3, ] <- unclass(with(df, by(y, x, FUN = mean)))

bxp(bx.p, add=T, boxfill="transparent", medcol="blue", boxwex=0.4,
    axes=F, outpch = NA, outlty="blank", boxlty="blank", whisklty="blank", staplelty="blank")
legend(x=3.8,y=90.5, lty=c(1, 1), lwd=rep(3, 2), col=c("red", "blue"), box.lwd=0.2,legend = c("median", "mean"), cex=0.8,horiz = FALSE, bg="transparent")

segments(x0 = seq(0.5, 10, 0.5), y0 = 50, y1 = 100, lty = 2, lwd = 0.75, col = "lightgrey")
segments(x0 = 0, x1 = 10, y0 = seq(50, 100, 5), lty = 2, lwd = 0.75, col = "lightgrey")
```

[image]